# Add additional information to product list item in widget

Tags: magento2, product-list, plugin, widget

I was able to add some additional information to the products in the category and the search-result page with a plugin.
Unfortunately it doesn't work for the widgets (product list widgets, related products etc.).

My di.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct">
      <plugin name="add_custom_block" type="MyVendor\MyModule\Plugin\FreeShipping" sortOrder="1" disabled="false" />
    </type>
</config>
```

My Plugin/FreeShipping.php:

```
<?php
namespace MyVendor\MyModule\Plugin;

class FreeShipping
{
    public function afterGetProductPrice(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct $subject,
        $result,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $_product
    ) {
        $shippingperitem=$_product->getShippingPeritem();
        $freeshipping=false;
        $storpickuponly=$_product->getStorepickupOnly();
        if (floatval($shippingperitem)<=0.000001) {
            $freeshipping=true;
        }
        $productId = $_product->getId(); //parent product id..
        $_configChild = $_product->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts($_product);
        $getChildId = [];

        foreach ($_configChild as $child) {
            if (floatval($child->getShippingPeritem())>0.000001) {
                $freeshipping=false;
            }
            if ($child->getStorepickupOnly()==true) {
                $storpickuponly==true;
            }
        }
        $shippinginfo="";
        if ($freeshipping==true && $storpickuponly==false) {
            $shippinginfo = "<div id='free-shipping-banner active'>";
            $shippinginfo .= __("Free shipping");
            $shippinginfo .= "</div>";
        } else {
            $shippinginfo = "<div id='free-shipping-banner'>";
            $shippinginfo .= "</div>";
        }
        return $result.$shippinginfo;
    }
}
```

Do I need to specify another plugin for another class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try plugin for the `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct` class. All other class like `Crosssell` `Upsell` `NewWidget` are extending this class and `AbstractProduct` class has `getProductPrice()` as public function so you can make plugin.

**UPDATE**

In widget phtml file `getProductPriceHtml()` used so you have to make plugin for the `getProductPriceHtml()`

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct">
      <plugin name="add_custom_block" type="Vendor\MyModule\Plugin\FreeShipping" sortOrder="1" disabled="false" />
    </type>    
</config>

I edited the di.xml - but I get the same result - the plugin isnt working for the widgets.

Comment: yes but change the name of plugin from `add_custom_block` to something else as this name already define for the `ListProduct` class

Comment: Do I also need to change something in the FreeShipping.php, as the function uses "Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" (as you can see in my question above)?

Comment: yes you have to change the `$subject` . But keep `FreeShipping.php` as it is and make another class because for the `ProductList` you need that class.

Comment: Now I added 2 plugins to my di.xml and created 2 php-files:

type="Vendor\MyModule\Plugin\FreeShippingWidget"  (with \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct $subject)

type="Vendor\MyModule\Plugin\FreeShipping" (with \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct $subject)

The effect is, that both outputs are shown on the category/search result page but are still not visible in the widgets...

Comment: which widget class you are using?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/121141/discussion-between-mario-and-rakesh-varma).